# Expressionengine: How to display single category information

Tags: categories, channel

OK, I have a very simple task ahead, which, somehow got complicated.

I'm creating a simple blog in EE, with categories. Filtering posts by categories works just fine, however, I'm trying to display additional category information ("category_description" field), when I open specific category.

like: www.example.com/apples/ or www.example.com/oranges/
(i don't want to use reserved word like category, because it looks ugly :)

So what I want is, to pull my category info from url (eg. apples) from segment_2, - i got that working, and display the information from apples on the page.

Tried:

```
{exp:channel:category_heading category_id="1"}

  <h2>{category_name}</h2>
  <p>{category_description}</p>

{/exp:channel:category_heading}`
```

Displays NOTHING

Tried:

```
{exp:channel:categories category="20"}

    <h2>{category_name}</h2>
    <p>{category_description}</p>

{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Displays ALL categories with "list" tags (I just want ONE without list)

Comment: You say you are pulling your category 'apples' from segment_2 yet in your example it is in segment_1.

Answer (score 1):

`exp:channel:category_heading` always use the URL to fetch data. There isn't a `category_id` parameter, despite it could be useful.

So, if you're not using the [category word indicator](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/global_channel_preferences.html#category-url-indicator) and the parameter `channel`, your other option is the [Query Module](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/query/).

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT cat_name AS category_name, cat_description AS category_description FROM `exp_categories` WHERE cat_id = 1"}
  <h2>{category_name}</h2>
  <p>{category_description}</p>
{/exp:query}
```

You should [**not** use segments on the query](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/query/#template-tags-inside-queries).